# How do you make three divs under each other?

Tags: css, positioning, styling, spacing

I am trying to create a website with the game minesweeper. I have already created the game itself I just need some help with styling. I feel there must be an easier way to do this.

I am trying to create three buttons on the left under each other (for easy, medium and hard) side of the page and the game next to it on the right. It should look somewhat like this:

```
Button       Gamefield
             Gamefield
Button       Gamefield
             Gamefield
Button       Gamefield
```

Comment: I am unable to understand `Button Gamefield Gamefield Button Gamefield Gamefield Button Gamefield`. Also, show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Wrap those 3 buttons in a div and game in another div. and give some width and float left to both the divs.